# How can I use GarageBand as a simple drum machine to play against?

Tags: garage-band

I am after a simple drum machine I can just set playing and then play along to, not to record and just to improvise.

GarageBand is something I have but don't know well, it seems to force me to work in bars and sections when I just want an infinite loop. Can I easily use it for this purpose or am I misusing my tool to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There's are two really easy ways to create drums in GarageBand, especially if you're not sure how to create drum patterns.

## Drummer Tracks

1. Create a Drummer Track
   [image]
2. Select the project tempo.
3. Choose the genre for your "drummer" to play.
   [image]
4. Further customize how the drummer plays by using the editor controls here.
   [image]

## Apple Loops

1. Click on the middle button.
   [image]
2. Choose "All drums" (loops may need to be downloaded and indexed first)
   [image]
3. Listen to the loops and choose one that matches the style you need.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

GarageBand can definitely give you infinite percussion loops. I can't speak to the desktop version of the program, but in the app you can select the drums and use the grid to randomize or create your own infinite drum loop.

On the grid screen, you can select the kind of kit you want, and then place the corresponding instruments in various regions of the grid; which controls the activity of that instrument. Randomizing the pattern will give you equally complementary patterns that will also loop until you tell them to stop.